# Is passing of Objects in Java memory-consuming

Tags: java, object

When I pass an Object to another Class in Java - is this memory consuming or not? Does the object function as some kind of pointer, such as c-language?

Or when passing it to another class's constructor - I am making a copy of the object?

for instance in Android

```
 Context context

 Class Foo = new Foo(this.context);
```

Comment: This question may be of use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 2):

Objects in Java aren't passed at all. Object *references* are passed by value. Passing references does not copy the contents, so only a few bytes (the size of the reference type) are used when passing them, see here for more clarification: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Passing object references to constructors has no specific semantics. It totally depends on the constructor whether it creates copies of the content.

Answer (score 2):

Object references are actually pointers, they store a memory address. They do not store an actual copy of the object's data. For example, this code in Java:

```
Object o = new Object();
System.out.println(o.toString());
```

is the same as this code in C++ (assuming there is an `Object` class):

```
Object *o = new Object();
cout << o.toString();
```

In C++, you can pass an actual copy of the object data if you want to. This is not possible in Java, because it is more efficient to just have a pointer and not consume a lot of memory.

However, if you pass an object to a constructor (or any method), it could do whatever it wants with it, including make a copy of it (using `clone`) or gather some data from it to use in constructing itself. So the constructor could make a copy, but you are not making a copy just by passing the object to a constructor.

See also: [Is Java "pass-by-reference"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 1):

`When I pass an Object to another Class in Java` To start with, you never pass an `object` is Java. Everything in Java is **Passed by Value**. Object are somewhat handled differently. **Object references** are passed by value. So, if you try to pass an object what is actually happening you are passing a reference of that object. And the called method creates it's own copy of the object reference(*passed by value principle*). `is this memory consuming or not` The answer is **Yes**. As a copy of reference is created *32 bits* of memory(In 32 bit JVM) is used on stack to point to same object on heap.